# How to add htaccess rewrite rule in Joomla

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, joomla1.5

I use Joomla 1.5.22 and mod_rewrite with nice links. But I would like to add also a redirection like this:

RewriteRule ^mail /squirrelmail

So if Someone enters www.mypage.com/mail he will be redirected to www.mypage.com/squirrelmail

How to update Joomla's .htaccess file in order for this to work? For now, if I use this Rule, it shows a Joomla 404 Error

Comment: Please add your current htaccess, and where you tried putting the rule (in front, or after).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.htaccess` find, and AFTER the following statement:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

ADD the following line

```
RewriteRule ^mail$ /squirrelmail [R=301,L]
```